# How to use youtube api to prevent advertorials

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, adsense

I have build a website for my customer with embedded you tube movies. Therefore I'm using a lot of API functions. Somehow while playing a movie, commercials of concurrent company's appear.

My customer claims it has to be my used code... I belief you have to set-up your you tube channel and ad sense channel correct but you cannot prevent it completely because you tube permit double click to show commercials also...

It's not: who is right or wrong but I need to know how to prevent Ads while playing.

I hope someone could share Some knowledge with me.

Have a nice day.

Best,
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't prevent ads when you play a video. 
We can see in the **[Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)** of YouTuve API in the part prohibitions :

> 7. modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the
>      YouTube player;

So, if ou want use the YouTube API Players, you can't add a system to block advertissement.

Comment: do you mean with your answer 'using the YouTube API Players, you can't add a system to block...' that there are other players that could block adds? On [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en) Google says that "Also, videos should be embedded using the standard click-to-play embed and not a scripted play." So for example: if I use the standard embed option under neath the YouTube movie the advertissements will not appear on the embedded YouTube movie?

Comment: nop, if there is ads, there is ads, you can't block ads. I mean if you're client use Ad-block there is no problem on your side...at least.